# Android: Keep Service alive when app evicted

Tags: android, multiprocessing, android-service

I'm creating a floating menu similar to Facebook's Chatheads.  I want this menu to be separate from my main process so that the main process can die without hurting the menu.  I noticed that Facebook's Messenger app supports this.  If you kill the Messenger app while a chathead is visible, the chathead sits there without issue.

In my app I tried using a separate process for my floating menu:

```
<service
    android:name="myservice"
    android:process=":otherprocess" />
```

Unfortunately, this separate process didn't help.  When I swipe away my app from the recents screen, my Activity AND my Service get destroyed.  I'm not sure why my separate Service process is getting killed, too, but I want it to stay around.

I know that I can use START_STICKY to get the menu Service to start again, but this still leads to the destruction of everything in the Service and a recreation.  I want the user to be able to swipe away the app without hurting the Service at all.